# Parse hex values into string for shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to put together what should be a fairly simple shell script.  The script will have a parameter that is a decimal value.  The script will need to convert the decimal to a hex value and then combine that value with a command to be run.

For example if I run the command

> ./myscript.sh 45

It would need to convert 45 to hex (2d) and then append 2d to the end of a string.

Comment: I started with echo "obase=16";  $1 | bc,  but that seemed to give me a hex value that I couldn't combine with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the function `print` that might be useful.

```sh
printf "%x" 45
2d
```

It works similarly to high level programming languages `print` function/call where it can transform a value using `%` formatting. Here, `%x`, formats the first given positional argument to its hex value.

Then you could utilize this by assigning the value to a variable and take it from there.

```sh
x=$(printf "%x" 45)
```

Also, the first argument to a script lives in `$1`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the d in 2d is lower case.  Apparently the command only accepts capital letters

Comment: @LorenZimmer Try `"%X"`

Comment: Wait, shouldn't that be `printf`, not `print`?

Comment: Yes printf did work.  Now I just need to figure out how to add a zero to the front if the value is below 10.

Comment: @LorenZimmer `"%02X"` should do that.